# Assertion failure error when trying to reload sections

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, uitableview, expand

I am creating one table based application using `TQMultistageTableView` library to expand sections. My requirement is if the user will tap on table sections then section background color should change to blue color, rest section background color should be white color if not selected/expanded. For this, I have created an array to save the section index and then I'm reloading this section.

Very first time (when my array is nil), its working fine. But the problem is when there is one section index saved in my array (as any one section is expanded/selected) and then I am trying to expand other section with reloading the second section, that time it's crashing with below error :

> *** Assertion failure in -[UITableView _endCellAnimationsWithContext:], /SourceCache/UIKit_Sim/UIKit-2935.137/UITableView.m:1368
>
> *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInternalInconsistencyException', reason: 'Invalid update: invalid
>   number of rows in section 1.  The number of rows contained in an
>   existing section after the update (0) must be equal to the number of
>   rows contained in that section before the update (3), plus or minus
>   the number of rows inserted or deleted from that section (0 inserted,
>   0 deleted) and plus or minus the number of rows moved into or out of
>   that section (0 moved in, 0 moved out).'

Here is my code :

//header open method

```
- (void)mTableView:(TQMultistageTableView *)mTableView1 willOpenHeaderAtSection:(NSInteger)section
{
    NSLog(@"Open Header ----%ld",section);
    NSDictionary *selectedSection = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%ld", (long)section] ,@"section" ,nil];

    for(int i=0;i<[ selectedArrayForSectionPlus count];i++)
    {
        if([[[selectedArrayForSectionPlus objectAtIndex:i] objectForKey:@"section"] isEqualToString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%ld", (long)section]])
        {
            [selectedArrayForSectionPlus removeObjectAtIndex:i];
            [self.mTableView.tableView reloadSections:[NSIndexSet indexSetWithIndex:section] withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationFade];

            return;
        }
    }

    [selectedArrayForSectionPlus addObject:selectedSection];

    [self.mTableView.tableView reloadSections:[NSIndexSet indexSetWithIndex:section] withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationFade];//here it is crashing
}
```

//header close method

```
- (void)mTableView:(TQMultistageTableView *)mTableView willCloseHeaderAtSection:(NSInteger)section
{    
    NSLog(@"Close Header ---%ld",section);

    for(int i=0;i<[ selectedArrayForSectionPlus count];i++)
    {
        if([[[selectedArrayForSectionPlus objectAtIndex:i] objectForKey:@"section"] isEqualToString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%ld", (long)section]])
        {
            [selectedArrayForSectionPlus removeObjectAtIndex:i];
            [self.mTableView.tableView reloadSections:[NSIndexSet indexSetWithIndex:section] withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationFade];

            return;
        }
    }
}
```

//viewForHeaderInSection method

```
- (UIView *)mTableView:(TQMultistageTableView *)mTableView viewForHeaderInSection:(NSInteger)section;
{
    UIView *view = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, self.mTableView.frame.size.width, 80)];

    for (int i = 0; i<selectedArrayForSectionPlus.count; i++) {
        if([[[selectedArrayForSectionPlus objectAtIndex:i] objectForKey:@"section"] isEqualToString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%ld", (long)section]])
        {

            [view setBackgroundColor:[UIColor colorWithRed:0/255.0 green:150/255.0 blue:214/255.0 alpha:1.0]];

        }
        else
        {
            [view setBackgroundColor:[UIColor whiteColor]];
        }
    }

    return view;
}
```

Does anyone have any idea how to reload the section?

Thanks for any pointers!

Answer (score 3):

When you are reloading a specific section, other sections data source (your data array) should be same as before.

I think you are updating the data source before the reload section call.

**Here is your problem**

You are not reloading the section 1 but some other. Before reload your data source (data array) contains three rows (records) for section 1 but when you reload the section, because of some reason your data source (data array index 1) is changed to 0 rows (records). index 1 of data source (data array)should contains three rows.

Check your data source when is populated and compare both before and after update.

Comment: @M Zubair Shamshad I have checked data source, my row array is totally different. It is working fine if I am clicking on any section when other sections are closed. Only the problem is if already one section is expanded and I am clicking on different section.

Comment: i am sure your data array is changed for some reason. the crash report says exactly the same thing what i am saying.

Comment: It can be also possible as It's crashing in openOrCloseHeaderWithSection method of TQMultistageTableView library, I am not getting the way to resolve this.

Comment: okay lets make a test... put a break point or nslog in `numnerOfRowsInSection` method. and compare the number of rows for section 1 before and after reload section call using the the same crash scenario.

Comment: I have tested in same scenerio, before number of rows for section 1 is 4 and after reloadSections of willOpenHeaderAtSection method..its crashing directly without calling numberOfRowInSection method.

Comment: what is the value of `section` in `willOpenHeaderAtSection` if it is beyond the the table limit???

Comment: Instead reloadSections, If I am reloading my table reloadData then before and after number of rows are coming correctly. But after this its crashing on openOrCloseHeaderWithSection method of TQMultistageTableView library.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/95582/discussion-between-anand-gautam-and-m-zubair-shamshad).

Answer (score 2):

Encapsulate your section reload calls in `beginUpdates` and `endUpdates` something like this:

```
[self.mTableView.tableView beginUpdates];
[selectedArrayForSectionPlus removeObjectAtIndex:i];
[self.mTableView.tableView reloadSections:[NSIndexSet indexSetWithIndex:section] withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationFade];
[self.mTableView.tableView endUpdates];
```

**EDIT:** Post discussion with OP.

1. Tap on section 1 calls `willOpenHeaderAtSection`. Keep track of the tapped section here.
2. Tap on section 2 calls `willCloseHeaderAtSection`. Match the section with the tracked section in #1. If matches, execute your `willCloseHeaderAtSection` code and reset the tracked section. If not matches simply return without executing your code.

Comment: @AbhinavThanks for your response, I have tried to reload section using beginUpdates  and endUpdates but still crashing.

Comment: Could you please double check on your model object which contains data for rows and section. Before every reload call, you need to ensure you model contain correct data.

Comment: The problem is suppose if I am clicking on second section then 'willOpenHeaderAtSection' is calling only and after that if I am again clicking on first section then both 1. 'willCloseHeaderAtSection' and 2. 'willOpenHeaderAtSection' is calling.

Comment: My code is working fine if I am clicking on any section when other sections are closed.

Comment: Got you. You would need to handle this a bit tricky way. Since you are removing objects when `willCloseHeaderAtSection` is being called, it creates problem when iOS trigger call to this method when u tap on any other section to expand it. You should track current opened/expanded cell section in `willOpenHeaderAtSection ` and execute your code inside `willCloseHeaderAtSection` only when section matches otherwise simply return. Reset the tracked section if it matches and execute your code in `willCloseHeaderAtSection`. I hope you understand what I mean.

Comment: I got your point, but willCloseHeaderAtSection is calling before willOpenHeaderAtSection method then how can I excute the code only inside willCloseHeaderAtSection.

Comment: Take a look my updated post. This is a high level algorithm of how I wanted it to be.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/95533/discussion-between-anand-gautam-and-abhinav).

Comment: Thanks this answer helped me.

Answer (score 0):

Here is Your Problem:

```
[self.mTableView.tableView reloadSections:[NSIndexSet indexSetWithIndex:section] withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationFade];
```

So before using this line add `[_mTableView reloadtable];`

Because there is a header and tableview if you left to update anything one ,i should be problem .

if your problem solved on the above line then its fine....

Comment: reloading the entire table should never be done directly before reloading a section of that table.

Answer (score 0):

I had Same Problem When You Open Section 1 Header And Update The Header while opening header At different section it use to throw the error so  here is what i did to work it fine
code for updating headers

```
[self.mTableView.tableView reloadSections:[NSIndexSet indexSetWithIndex:section] withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationFade];
```

and only one thing more you need to do is In the TQMultistageTableView.m File the method name **-(void)openOrCloseHeaderWithSection:(NSInteger)section**
just Paste Below Code And Your done

```
  [self.tableView beginUpdates];
NSMutableArray *deleteIndexPaths = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
NSMutableArray *insertIndexPaths = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];

NSInteger oldSection = self.openedIndexPath.section;
NSInteger newSection = section;

if (oldSection <= -1)
{

    if (oldSection != newSection)
    {
        insertIndexPaths = [self buildInsertRowWithSection:newSection];
    }
}
else
{

    if (oldSection != newSection && newSection > -1)
    {

        deleteIndexPaths = [self buildDeleteRowWithSection:oldSection];
        insertIndexPaths = [self buildInsertRowWithSection:newSection];
    }
    else
    {
         deleteIndexPaths = [self buildDeleteRowWithSection:oldSection];
    }
}


if ([deleteIndexPaths count] > 0)
{
    [self.tableView deleteRowsAtIndexPaths:deleteIndexPaths withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationFade];
}
if ([insertIndexPaths count] > 0)
{
    [self.tableView insertRowsAtIndexPaths:insertIndexPaths withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationLeft];
}

[self.tableView endUpdates];
```